# Recursive function with a specific runtime of Theta(...)

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm stuck with this homework I got from my Algorithms course:

> Write a recursive function with a runtime of Theta(n^4 logn).

I thought something like this, but I'm very unsure about my approach.

```
function(int n)
{
   for-loop (1..n^4)
     //do something

   return function(n/2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be unsure, your function has some problems:

1. It doesn't has initial values, and runs forever.
2. If you set initial value for your function it will be as:

   T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n^4)

and by master theorem this is Θ(n^4).

Hint: You should increase coefficient of `T(n/2)`, but how much? find it yourself. For this increasing you can call it `x` times.

---

By Master theorem `log n` happens when we have a recursion like this:

> T(n) = a T(n/b) + n<sup>a/b</sup>

In your case you have a/b = 4, so you can fix b = 2 and a = 8 to achieve this.

> T(n) = 8T(n/2) + n<sup>4</sup>

and for arriving to this, you can call T(n/2) for 8 times.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: n<sup>4</sup> could be four nested loops from 1 to n. Logarithmic run-time factor is usually obtained by halving problem size recursively until reaching 1. Your proposal kind of works, but is quite blunt and you could even do

```
func(int n)
  for i = 1 to n^4 log n
     nop()
```

but I don't believe this is something that's being looked for.

Comment: His algorithm is not n^4 log n

Comment: true, it also never terminates

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is sane, and your insecurity is normal. You should now prove that your algorithm is Theta(n^4 log n). Apply your normal algorithmic analysis techniques to show that `function` executes `do something` n^4 log_2 n times.

Hint: Count how many times `function` is called recursively and how often the loop runs in each call. You'll see that there is still a small bug in your function; the `n` for the `n^4` factor is reduced in each recursive call.

Comment: his algorithm is not totally wrong, even your answer seems to indicate that he is close. Stop spamming

Comment: @UmNyobe, Seems you are spam generator, If you think OPs algorithm is not wrong write your own answer and describe how it's correct.